# JAX-RS Path annotation URI template

Tags: path, jax-rs, uritemplate

I have this code method in a java class with JAX-RS:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/reports/{id: (zerotrips|notrips|tripsummary|rejectedtrips){1}/{0,1}}")
@GET
public Response get(@Context HttpServletRequest aRequest){
   ....
}
```

Could someone give some examples of the url mapped by the expression in the @Path annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/reports/zerotrips
/reports/zerotrips/
```

Replace `zerotrips` with any of the other ones on between the parenthesis

```
(zerotrips|notrips|tripsummary|rejectedtrips){1}
```

This says any one of the values in the parenthesis. `|` means "or". The `{1}` means "once".

```
/{0,1}
```

means with or without a slash. `{0,1}` means zero to once.

A pattern followed by `{}` gives the number of times it is allowed. For example `a{3,5}` means an `a` three to five times. So the following would match: `aaa`, `aaaa`, `aaaaa`, but `aa` would not match.